# IIS 7.0 ASP.Net 3.5 Application fails when multiple users log on

Tags: exception, iis-7

I have an ASP.Net 3.5 Application hosted on Windows Server 2008 machine using IIS 7. There is a seperate application pool for this application. 
The problem I have is that as soon as 2-3 users access website simultaneously, it starts throwing exceptions on almost any task performed say e.g. an exception during logging in the user using built in aspnet_membership. The same things work fine when there is only one user using it. 
Any suggestions what things I need to test for? 
Thanks, 
Ali

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem like this for some web-application, but in my case I was using IIS 6.0. After analyzing the application by means of some **DevPartner** tools for analyzing **memory usage** we realize that some components were **consuming excessive resources**, by replacing the toolkit we were using for simple .Net controls the applications stop crashing. *Most of the crashes are due to problems in code*. Also check the web config in the following points: **sessionState**, **authentication**. Disable custom errors (**customErrors**) to view the error details. See the **application event's log** to check the error description.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I do when setting up a website of this nature is to uncouple the session state from `InProc` to `StateServer`. Oftentimes I find that an application recycle or even an application level exception can cause the w3wp.exe process to crash and reload which dumps session errors. As with @Arce Brito's recommendation, you should do everything you can to find the root cause of the exception as decoupling the session will really only mask the symptom.

Comment: Thanks Arce Brito and Joel Etherton for your valuable inputs. 
I have worked on both aspects, optimized some code which I though was causing the application to slow down (after which the speed has improved noticeably). Also my session state mode is now StateServer but still as soon as multiple users log in, the application crashes. I restart the MSSQL Service and the application is OK again (until multiple users login). The issue seems to be with the way SQL server is handling multiple requests. Any suggestions on this front?